# Como funciona el Copy-and-swap?

Tags: c++, c++11

He estado revisando las novedades de C++11 y C++14, y no entiendo como 
funciona el copy-and-swap.

Como ejemplo:

```
class dumb_array
{
public:
// ...

friend void swap(dumb_array& first, dumb_array& second) // nothrow
{
    // enable ADL (not necessary in our case, but good practice)
    using std::swap;

    // by swapping the members of two objects,
    // the two objects are effectively swapped
    swap(first.mSize, second.mSize);
    swap(first.mArray, second.mArray);
}

// ...
};


dumb_array& operator=(dumb_array other) // (1)
{
    swap(*this, other); // (2)
    return *this;
}
```

(La fuente del código es  [GManNickG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87234/gmannickg), gracias por la respuesta en [este](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) post.)

No entiendo por qué el objeto se copia en lugar de intercambiarse.
Al llamar a swap(a,b), según la definición de *std::swap*,los valores deberían intercambiarse
operator= devuelve el objeto, que ahora tiene los atributos de  **other**. Pero por qué  **other** sigue teniendo sus atributos en lugar de haberlos intercambiado?

Lo siento si mi pregunta suena estúpida, pero estoy intentando asimilar todos los conceptos que tiene C++ moderno y me está costando bastante.

Comment: This is spanish site, translate your question please

Comment: @AndoniAlda lo siento, no me di cuenta de que estaba posteando a la versión española. Editado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dumb_array& operator=(dumb_array other) // (1)
{
    swap(*this, other); // (2)
    return *this;
}
```

(1) Observa que el parámetro *other* **es una copia** del argumento de llamada.

(2) swap(*this, other); intercambia los miembros de *this con los de other (con este other de (1), **que es la copia** del objeto que se le pasó al invocar esta función).

Capisce?

Comment: No sé como no me di cuenta de que lo pasa por valor.